# Reset on Hover (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, timer, hover, slide

```
$("#notification").slideDown("slow").delay(2000).slideUp("slow");
```

.. works, but I want to add a condition so that if #notification is hovered, the timer/delay is stopped until mouseout. Then On mouseout the timer starts and then eventually the element is hidden (unless its not hovered again).

Thanks!

Comment: When does the element slideDown event occur right now? On hover()? document.ready()?

Comment: Its based on cookie, if cookie not found, slidedown...

Comment: The way you describe it, theoretically, if you hover after 1999 miliseconds the timer will stop, and then when you mouseout again there's only 1 milisecond left before it hides again. Is this a must? Because it'd be a lot easier to just reset the timer when you hover :)

Comment: Ahh I think I understand, you probably have some sort of a notification and/or button that gets shown - then hidden in about 2 seconds, you want it to prevent from hiding when someone mouseovers the notification. Just a note - adding context to your questions will really help with answers.

Comment: Sorry, yes, onload if cookie is not found, this notification slidesdown, and I don't want it to close if the user is reading (mouseover) it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you wanna be able to stop the delay/animation if you hover the element?

Use `clearQueue()` for that

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(cookieIsPresent) {
        $("#notification").hover(function() {
            $(this).stop(true, true).clearQueue(); // You might not need to use clearQueue() but test it out
        }, function() {
            $(this).delay(2000).slideUp("slow");
        }).slideDown("slow").delay(2000).slideUp("slow");
    }
});
```

Comment: erm..how should the whole thing look with slidedown/slideup and delay too?

Comment: You're welcome :) Try removing the clearQueue and see if that works, I've heard that stop() might not work on delay() but that might've been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try handling the **onmouseover** (not onmousehover) event.

Comment: You could try put a bit more effort into the answer. P.S. There's no onmousehover event.